# How to solve the following equation numerically?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, matrix, physics, eigenvalues

In the following code, if the matrix "n = (-I*(m1)) + (m2)" in the differential equation contains only the matrix "m1", I will get the answer, but if the matrix "n" is the sum of the two matrices "m1" and "m2", it will not answer. why? Please advise

```
Ω0 = 2 π*10*10^6; Γ = 
2 π*22*10^3; t0 = (Pi Sqrt[2]/(Ω0)); T = (7.2/2)*
t0; σ = T/6; tf = T;
FSR = (2 Pi*10^7);
s[t_] := 0.5 (1 + Tanh[(t - (T/2))/σ]);
ali[t_] := Sech[(t - (T/2))/σ];
WP[t_] := Ω0 (1/(Sqrt[2])) ali[t] Sin[Pi (s[t])/2];
WS[t_] := Ω0 (1/(Sqrt[2])) ali[t] Cos[Pi (s[t])/2];


m = {{0, WP[t], WP[t], WP[t], 0}, {WP[t], -FSR, 0, 0, -WS[t]}, {WP[t],
     0, 0, 0, WS[t]}, {WP[t], 0, 0, FSR, -WS[t]}, {0, -WS[t], 
     WS[t], -WS[t], 0}};

 q = Eigenvectors[m];
qq1 = Normalize[q[[1]]];
qq2 = Normalize[q[[2]]];
qq3 = Normalize[q[[3]]];
qq4 = Normalize[q[[4]]];
qq5 = Normalize[q[[5]]];

Ali1 = {{D[qq1, t][[1]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq1, t][[2]], 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {D[qq1, t][[3]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq1, t][[4]], 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {D[qq1, t][[5]], 0, 0, 0, 0}};
Vali1 = ConjugateTranspose[Ali1];
Kazi1 = Ali1.Vali1;

 Ali2 = {{D[qq2, t][[1]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq2, t][[2]], 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {D[qq2, t][[3]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq2, t][[4]], 0, 0, 0, 
  0}, {D[qq2, t][[5]], 0, 0, 0, 0}};
Vali2 = ConjugateTranspose[Ali2];
Kazi2 = Ali2.Vali2;

Ali3 = {{D[qq3, t][[1]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq3, t][[2]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq3, t][[3]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq3, t][[4]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq3, t][[5]], 0, 0, 0, 0}};
Vali3 = ConjugateTranspose[Ali3];
Kazi3 = Ali3.Vali3;

Ali4 = {{D[qq4, t][[1]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq4, t][[2]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq4, t][[3]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq4, t][[4]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq4, t][[5]], 0, 0, 0, 0}};
Vali4 = ConjugateTranspose[Ali4];
Kazi4 = Ali4.Vali4;

 Ali5 = {{D[qq5, t][[1]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq5, t][[2]], 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {D[qq5, t][[3]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq5, t][[4]], 0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {D[qq5, t][[5]], 0, 0, 0, 0}};
 Vali5 = ConjugateTranspose[Ali5];
Kazi5 = Ali5.Vali5;


 m1 = {{0, WP[t], WP[t], WP[t], 
0}, {WP[t], -FSR - I (Γ/2), 0, 0, -WS[t]}, {WP[t], 
0, -I (Γ/2), 0, WS[t]}, {WP[t], 0, 0, 
FSR - I (Γ/2), -WS[t]}, {0, -WS[t], WS[t], -WS[t], 
0}};


  m2 = Kazi1 + Kazi2 + Kazi3 + Kazi4 + Kazi5;

 n = (-I*(m1)) + (m2);

 sol1 = NDSolve[{D[c[t], t] == (n).c[t],
 c[0] == {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, c, {t, 0, 2 tf}];

 ans = Evaluate[c[t] /. sol1[[1]]][[5]];
 ans1 = Abs[ans]^2;
 Plot[ans1, {t, 0, 2 tf}, Frame -> True]
```

In the following code, if the matrix "n = (-I*(m1)) + (m2)" in the differential equation contains only the matrix "m1", I will get the answer, but if the matrix "n" is the sum of the two matrices "m1" and "m2", it will not answer. why? Please advise. How tosolve this problem??

Comment: Maybe it's because `m2` is an extremely complex 5x5 matrix with `LeafCount` 15303452. `LeafCount[sol1] ` will not even complete. You should  explain where this problem comes from, ideally with some background info and LaTeX equations.

Comment: Thank you, yes m2 is an complex matrix. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot solve it like this. If you provided information about where the code comes from or what real world problem it solves then it might be possible write it differently that avoids the hugely complex matrices, but until then it is completely intractable.