# how can I correct this code?

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, simplifying-expressions, physics, eigenvalues

I need to calculate matrix m1 according to following algorithm. Then, I have to put it in the differential equation. However, matrix m1 is complex and therefore the differential equation does not work.
How can I correct this code to get an answer?

```
 Ω0 = 2 π*10*10^6; Γ = 
 2 π*22*10^3; t0 = (Pi Sqrt[2]/(Ω0)); T = (7.2/2)*
 t0; σ = T/6; tf = T;
 FSR = (2 Pi*10^7);
 s[t_] := 0.5 (1 + Tanh[(t - (T/2))/σ]);
 ali[t_] := Sech[(t - (T/2))/σ];
 WP[t_] := Ω0 (1/(Sqrt[2])) ali[t] Sin[Pi (s[t])/2];
 WS[t_] := Ω0 (1/(Sqrt[2])) ali[t] Cos[Pi (s[t])/2];


 m = {{0, WP[t], WP[t], WP[t], 0}, {WP[t], -FSR, 0, 0, -WS[t]}, {WP[t],
 0, 0, 0, WS[t]}, {WP[t], 0, 0, FSR, -WS[t]}, {0, -WS[t], 
 WS[t], -WS[t], 0}};

q = Eigenvectors[m];
qq1 = Normalize[q[[1]]];
qq2 = Normalize[q[[2]]];
qq3 = Normalize[q[[3]]];
qq4 = Normalize[q[[4]]];
qq5 = Normalize[q[[5]]];

Ali1 = {{D[qq1, t][[1]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq1, t][[2]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq1, t][[3]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq1, t][[4]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq1, t][[5]], 0, 0, 0, 0}};
Vali1 = ConjugateTranspose[Ali1];
Kazi1 = Ali1.Vali1;

Ali2 = {{D[qq2, t][[1]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq2, t][[2]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq2, t][[3]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq2, t][[4]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq2, t][[5]], 0, 0, 0, 0}};
Vali2 = ConjugateTranspose[Ali2];
Kazi2 = Ali2.Vali2;

Ali3 = {{D[qq3, t][[1]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq3, t][[2]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq3, t][[3]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq3, t][[4]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq3, t][[5]], 0, 0, 0, 0}};
Vali3 = ConjugateTranspose[Ali3];
Kazi3 = Ali3.Vali3;

Ali4 = {{D[qq4, t][[1]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq4, t][[2]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq4, t][[3]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq4, t][[4]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq4, t][[5]], 0, 0, 0, 0}};
Vali4 = ConjugateTranspose[Ali4];
Kazi4 = Ali4.Vali4;

Ali5 = {{D[qq5, t][[1]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq5, t][[2]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq5, t][[3]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {D[qq5, t][[4]], 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {D[qq5, t][[5]], 0, 0, 0, 0}};
Vali5 = ConjugateTranspose[Ali5];
Kazi5 = Ali5.Vali5;


  m1 = {{0, WP[t], WP[t], WP[t], 
  0}, {WP[t], -FSR - I (Γ/2), 0, 0, -WS[t]}, {WP[t], 
   0, -I (Γ/2), 0, WS[t]}, {WP[t], 0, 0, 
  FSR - I (Γ/2), -WS[t]}, {0, -WS[t], WS[t], -WS[t], 
  0}};


 m2 = Kazi1 + Kazi2 + Kazi3 + Kazi4 + Kazi5;

 n = (-I*(m1)) + (m2);

  sol1 = NDSolve[{D[c[t], t] == (n).c[t],
  c[0] == {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, c, {t, 0, 2 tf}];

 ans = Evaluate[c[t] /. sol1[[1]]][[5]];
  ans1 = Abs[ans]^2;
  Plot[ans1, {t, 0, 2 tf}, Frame -> True]
```

I need to calculate matrix m1 according to following algorithm. Then, I have to put it in the differential equation. However, matrix m1 is complex and therefore the differential equation does not work.
How can I correct this code to get an answer?

Comment: You've duplicated this question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230255/how-can-i-correct-this-code-to-get-an-answer and here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230227/how-to-solve-the-following-equation-numerically

Comment: The previous question code was incomplete

Comment: Then you should edit the question to include more details. Do not create a duplicate question.